# Putty - output received data to a separate window

Tags: windows, putty

I'm using putty to connect to a custom app in order to feed it some commands and receive logged information. The problem that there's too much log data and it's spamming my putty terminal window. What would be really nice, I suppose, is to have all these received data a separate window, separate from command window. 
Of course I could change my app to send log data to a different port(and create second putty session to receive this data), but I'm wondering if it possible with putty - to separate  command and log windows?

Comment: I think you should try and contact the team at http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

Comment: @Ingo - thanks for the pointer, found in their "non-wish list" - [MUD-client-like features (separate input window, etc)](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/mud-client.html)